# How markers move without refreshing the application, using the GPS of android

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps, react-native

I currently on module of tracking the users using the geolocation of google map. I started coding this since 3 days ago, I use the react-native-maps for the mapview, since I already plot all the codes displaying my current location and watching my position where I am now. I found out when I walk outside my marker is not moving, and I try to debug the state of my lat and long, the watching function is not working well.

**Question: How to make a real time moving marker without refreshing the application using the GPS of android.**

**Testing Materials**:

Mobile Phone Vivo V9
USB Cable,
Mobile Phone OS: Funtouch OS,
Android Version 8.1 Oreo

**Android Manifest:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" />
```

Since I already done creating the function, I will show you guys my codes, so the other having same issue will solved there problem also,

**This is my current location on my mobile phone,**

[image: My current location]

As you can see on the top of my google map, is my current location or the lat and long of my location.

**14.6211748 , 121.0138529**

Now since I already get my lat and long, Using the watch position the GPS automatically detect my lat and long every time move right? The problem here
why my lat and long is not changing in real time?

Is there other function for the real time update of lat long?

Now guys, This is my code for that,

**My State:**

```
this.state = {

  currentLocation: {
    latitude:0,
    longitude:0,
    latitudeDelta:0,
    longitudeDelta:0
  },

  updatedLocation: {
    latitude:0,
    longitude:0,
    latitudeDelta:0,
    longitudeDelta:0
  },

  markerPosition: {
    latitude:0,
    longitude:0,
    latitudeDelta:0,
    longitudeDelta:0
  }


}
```

**My async Current Location**

```
 watchID: ?number = null;
  async _currentPosition() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {

      //lat and long current
      var lat = parseFloat(position.coords.latitude)
      var long = parseFloat(position.coords.longitude)

      var currentLocationValue = {
        latitude:lat,
        longitude:long,
        latitudeDelta:LATTITUDE_DELTA,
        longitudeDelta:LONGTITUDE_DELTA
      }

      this.setState({currentLocation:currentLocationValue})
      this.setState({markerPosition:currentLocationValue})

      console.log(currentLocationValue);


   },(error) => alert(JSON.stringify(error)),
   {enableHighAccuracy: true, distanceFilter: 1, timeout: 1000})
  }
```

**For watching position function:**

```
    async _updatedPosition() {
    this.watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition((position) => {

        //lat and long current
        var lat = parseFloat(position.coords.latitude)
        var long = parseFloat(position.coords.longitude)

        var updateLocationValue = {
          latitude:lat,
          longitude:long,
          latitudeDelta:LATTITUDE_DELTA,
          longitudeDelta:LONGTITUDE_DELTA
        }

        this.setState({updatedLocation:updateLocationValue})
        this.setState({markerPosition:updateLocationValue})

        console.log(updateLocationValue);


    },(error) => alert(JSON.stringify(error)),
    {enableHighAccuracy: true, distanceFilter: 1, timeout: 1000})
  }
```

**My Component Mounts:**

```
     componentDidMount() {
    this._currentPosition();
    this._updatedPosition();

  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(this.watchID)
  }
```

**My Render function:**

```
  render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>

          <MapView 
              style = {styles.mapcontainer}
              region = {this.state.currentLocation}
              onRegionChange={this.onRegionChange}

              >

              <MapView.Marker 
                  coordinate={this.state.markerPosition}>
                  <View style={styles.radius}>
                      <View style={styles.marker}/>
                  </View>
              </MapView.Marker>

          </MapView>
          <Text>
            {this.state.updatedLocation.latitude},{this.state.updatedLocation.longitude}
          </Text>
        </View>
      )
  }
```

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55203059/edit) your question to include more detail as to how you are testing. If you are using a emulator/device, which device and version of Android OS it is running. List the steps you are using to test and for how long (mock location provider or not). Also show your Android Manifest. Note that a `distanceFilter` of 1 on a real device would probably only work in an empty field with a fully visible sky, not a town or city.

Comment: Noted for this @MorrisonChang